# Can I clone my laptop os and host it with VMware Workstation 8?

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation

Does it make a difference in speed when I use a shared vm instead of a native os? I'm using Linux for web development with a laptop. My server isn't the fastest but it's nice to have this new feature in the new Workstation 8.

Does it makes sense when I want to learn? Does it works with compressed images?

Comment: Do you want to run your laptop as a VM on a different machine, or do you want to run VMWare Workstation on your laptop with current image running as a VM?

Comment: @Ole_Brun: I want to run it on my server. I've a vps and a desktop box. Would it run on a vps solution?

Comment: vps? Is this a virtual private server at some IPS or do you have a physical server?

Comment: @Ole_Brun: A virtual private server at some IPS. At my home I've a deskop box. I can run the vm on my desktop box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to day exactly what the performance impact will be by virtualizing a physical machine, but working remotely towards a vps will most probably be slower. This is because the GUI will require a large amount of data to be transferred over the network. Personally I am sometimes working on remote machines through VMWare vSphere, and even though they run on powerful servers, it feels quite a lot slower than any of my local machines.

However, if you virtualize an old laptop and run it on a more powerful local desktop machine as a VM, you can actually get better performance.